# css: Keeping browser centered when zoomed out

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

in css how to make sure the my page stays centered when i zoom out with equal white space on both sides. now it is all to the left when zoomed out

`.div {
position:absolute 
top:0px;
left:0px;
}`

Comment: Your content is not centered to begin with, it's absolutely-positioned to the top-left. Why would zooming change this?

Comment: look @ http://jsfiddle.net/chrisvenus/pdQrQ/6/

Answer (score 1):

.div { margin: 10px auto; }

the auto will center the div so the left and right will have same space